# iOS - How To Position a View Fixed Within a Certain Area On a Background Image

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

This is the layout that I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I want to position the circular yellow button within the small circular area of the background in any iPhone. The circular area is not centred in that image.

This is so far what I tried:

- First, I added a UIView with 1px x 1px, transparent background colour to the centre of the whole layout. I call that the center point
- Then I will set vertical spacing between centre point and the yellow button.
- I will also set leading constraint between the yellow button and the super view.
- Then, I will set aspect ratio (yellow button width to yellow button height).
- Another aspect ratio (yellow button to background image).

However, the outcome is really not what I expect it should be. It is alright that if the background image is distorted, I just want the yellow button to stay inside the circular area of the background image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position your circle relative to the background, set a constraint to align the trailing edge of the circle with the trailing edge of the image view, and then set the multiplier to an appropriate value like `214:640`.  This will cause the circle to move right by the correct amount as the screen size increases.

Likewise, align the circle bottom to the image view bottom and set the multiplier to an appropriate value like `478:900` and it will keep your circle aligned as the screen grows.

Play with the ratios until they look good on one phone size (like the iPhone 5S), then they'll work for the 6S and 6S Plus.

Set the circle width equal to the image view width and set the multiplier to `100:320`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go that far, I would make one button that fits the entire screen, set the button image to be the whole image including the yellow circle. Then use similar code below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  // Get the specific point that was touched
  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
  if (point.x * 100 / parentView.width in range (0-100) && point.y*100 / parentView.heiht in range (0-100)){
       // write your button event handler here.
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, what if I still have other buttons that needs to be position in some certain point also(actually I do have). There are other buttons that have to be positioned on top of the lines. Sorry, I didn't mention that. 
So, by doing what you just said, I'll just have to make an image with all the buttons attached, and just detect the touch points. But isn't it also a problem to detect the touch points correctly?

Comment: You need to worry about how the application look like, then in your code based on the parent width and height you can easily find the region of each button. I will edit my answer for you.

Comment: I modified the answer so you can only say the range of the percentage your buttons would cover in both vertical and horizontal directions. that should be easy now